# Securing API-KEYs while running CIrcle Ci Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara-webkit, circleci, routific-api

I've this Routific API-Key, and i want it not to expose while running Circle Ci tests. And without hitting on it i can pass my specs. How can i not expose my API-KEY and still be able to pass the tests?

Comment: Use ENV vars. https://12factor.net/config

Comment: Wont that be exposed then in circle ci?

Comment: Only if you set the env vars on the CI server.

Answer (score 1):

You can set them through the Project Settings > Environment Variables section of CirclCI - https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/environment-variables/#setting-environment-variables-for-all-commands-without-adding-them-to-git , which will make them only available in your runs of the project tests and not in your code repo.  Alternatively you can create an encrypted file - https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/environment-variables/#keeping-encrypted-environment-variables-in-source-code - in your code and then set the key in the Environment variables section of CircleCI

Answer (score 0):

I requested Routific locally for once and then received the response and saved it. Made a factory a factory which had this response and then used accordingly where needed. In my conditions, this was the only way i could go for, as the API wasnt allowed to be on even Circle Ci.